# SQL- Select a value within a cursor loop

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I want to select the result value at the end of my loop. I'm simplifying the code from my original problem. The status could be 1 ou 0. This loop is to check if there any '1' inside the result of my SELECT UNIQUE query. If "yes", then the result of my function must be one (or TRUE) at all time.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR status_cursor is(SELECT UNIQUE status
                            FROM    src_table st, bucket_table bt, many_table mt
                            WHERE   st.id = bt.st_id
                            AND    bt.mt_id = mt.id);
    result BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    FOR vals IN status_cursor
    LOOP
        IF vals.status = 1 THEN result := TRUE;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT result FROM DUAL; <-- this line does not work see error msg. 
END;
```

I get this error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 20, column 9:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 20, column 2:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Comment: What do you expect that last select to do? Where should result go? Is this in a procedure, a function, or somewhere else?

Comment: This would eventually become a function. But meanwhile, I need to test it as a simple query (procedure).

I expect the last select to be the result of my query.

Comment: If it's a function, the you need to return rather than that strange select that doesn't go anywhere. If not, you need select into something - but it doesn't make sense to select a value you already know from dual - that's just an expensive no-op.

Comment: That's great! So what would be my solution as a procedure ? I would try to make it work as a function. But if there was no function, would it be possible to get the value of "result" ? The "select into something", how does it work ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the result"? You already have it. If you want to return it to something, then you **need** a function. If you want to display it, you could use dbms_output.

Comment: @LAL please see my reply, i post a sql code that will be useful perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG).

"...You cannot pass a BOOLEAN value to the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT or DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE subprogram. To print a BOOLEAN value, use an IF or CASE statement to translate it to a character value...

Because SQL has no data type equivalent to BOOLEAN, you cannot:

- Assign a BOOLEAN value to a database table column
- Select or fetch the value of a database table column into a BOOLEAN variable
- Use a BOOLEAN value in a SQL statement, SQL function, or PL/SQL function invoked from a SQL statement

..."

I do not understand the procedure, but maybe this will be useful, for this case, you should not use a **CURSOR**:

```
SELECT UNIQUE COUNT(status) INTO result
FROM    src_table st, bucket_table bt, many_table mt
WHERE   st.id = bt.st_id AND    bt.mt_id = mt.id
AND status = 1

/*
    IF result > 0 
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
*/
```

Comment: You could lose the UNIQUE and add a "and rownum <= 1" on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
dbms_output.put_line(CASE result WHEN TRUE THEN 'TRUE' WHEN FALSE THEN 'FALSE' END);
```